# Induced action is proper discontinuous

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-actions

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective map, and let $G$ act on $X$ such that for each $g\in G$ and $x,x'\in X$  $f(x')=f(x)$ implies $f(g\cdot x)=f(g\cdot x')$. Further assume that the group action on $X$ is proper discontinuous.

In the above situation, we get an induced action on $Y$. But is this action again proper discontinuous?

My attempt so far: Let $U\subset X$ with $(g\cdot U \cap U \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow g=e)$.
Set $V=f(U)$ and let $y\in g\cdot V \cap V$, i.e. $y=g\cdot y'$ for some $y'\in V$. As $V=f(U)$, we can find $x,x' \in U$ such that $y=f(x)$ and $y' =f(x')$. Then we have $f(g\cdot x)=f(x')$ by the definition of the action on $Y$.
However, I need $g\cdot x=x'$ in order to get a contradiction.

Did I miss something? Do I need more assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counterexample, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \{0\}$ where $G = \mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ by integer valued translations.

Comment: Thanks, somehow i didn't think of this simple example. Unfortunately, this illustrates that even if we put more assumptions on $f$, it will be hard to get a proper discontinuous action. For example if we demand $f$ proper, we can consider instead of $\mathbb R$ a compact space as $X$. Maybe I need to put assumptions on $Y$. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll need a *very* very strong condition on $f$. For example, assuming local compactness of $X$ and $Y$, it will be necessary that the pre-image under $f$ of every compact subset of $Y$ is a compact subset of $X$.

Comment: Sorry, but could you expand on that? So let $f$ and the group action on $X$ be continuous (which I always assumed but forgot to mention). Further assume now that $f$ is proper, then for any $K\subset Y$ we have $g.K$ is compact. But why does this help?

Comment: What I said is that it is *necessary* that $f$ be proper.  In other words, if the induced action of $G$ on $Y$ is properly discontinuous then $f$ is a proper map.  And perhaps I meant to assume not just that $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact, but something like that they are metric spaces in which closed balls are compact. My point is, though, that for the induced action on $Y$ to be properly discontinuous is a *very difficult* property to achieve in a general setting. So difficult that it was very easy to find counterexamples, as my answer and the answer of @TsemoAristide demonstrate.

Comment: But why is $f$ proper in that case? I see that under these assumptions I can pick a compact neighbourhood of point which is contained in an open set like in the definition of proper discontinuous. But then how do I go on?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$ where $S^1$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ by the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $n.x=x+n$ We denote by $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ the quotient map. Consider $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$ endowed with the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $n.(x,y)=(x+n,p(y+nc))$ where $c$ is irrational number.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ defined by $f(x,y)=y$, the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ is proper on $\mathbb{Z}\times S^1$ but not on $S^1$.